# Angular2 testing: Missing 'angularCli.config' entry in Karma config

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to run 'npm test' in my Angular2 project but it gives me the below error:

"Missing 'angularCli.config' entry in Karma config"

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question:
Just found out that I had no config file and environment defined for angularCli in the 'karma.conf' file, the angularCli declaration should look like this in karma.conf:

angularCli: {
      config: './angular-cli.json',
      environment: 'dev'
    }

this defines the config file and environment for angularCli.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the fix was a matter of upgrading `karma` from version `1.1.0` to version `1.3.0`:

```
$ npm install karma@1.3.0 --save-dev
```

Comment: I bet that upgrade added the angular-cli config and envi correctly

Comment: Actually in my case the `angularCli.config` entry already existed in the Karma config. It was just not being picked up by `karma` version `1.1.0`.